# RSA Encryption in JavaCard

Tags: php, openssl, rsa, public-key-encryption, javacard

I hope anyone can help me with my problem. 
I'm developing a javacard applet and my task is to encrypt a secret (stored in the applet) with the public key of a server. The returning cipher will be send to a server afterwrds - php script on the server - where the cipher should be decrypted with the servers private key again.

And The problem is that the decryption in the php script (openssl_private_decrypt(...)) doesn't return anything, so it fails anywhere.

PS: I also saw some javacard RSA encryption examples and nearly all of them are using a private key for encryption which means in my opinion that the data is only be signed, not encrypted, am I right?

Here is some example code from the javacard applet:

```
byte[] secret ={ (byte)0x01,(byte)0x02,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x04}
public Crypto() {
    RSAPublicKey rsaPublicKey = (RSAPublicKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(
    KeyBuilder.TYPE_RSA_PUBLIC, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_RSA_2048, false);
    Cipher rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_RSA_PKCS1, false);
    encryptSecretWithPubKey();
}
.....
// here are some methods for setting the public key
.....

public byte[] encryptSecretWithPubKey() {
    if (!isRSAKeyInitialized) {
        ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_CONDITIONS_NOT_SATISFIED);
    }
    // make sure the blocks size which should be encrypted is not longer
    // than 53 bytes; see ALG_RSA_PKCS1 definition for encryption.
    if (secret.length >= rsaKeyModulus.length - 11) {
       // normally not the case, so ignore it for this test
    }
    rsaCipher.init(rsaPublicKey, Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
    final byte[] encryptedMsg = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray(
            (short) 256, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);

    if (rsaPublicKey.isInitialized())
        rsaCipher.doFinal(secret, (short) 0,
                (short) secret.length, encryptedMsg, (short) 0);
    return encryptedMsg; 
}
```

And here are the function I use for decryption in the php script:

```
public function decrypt($data)
{ // data is in binary format
    if (openssl_private_decrypt($data, $decrypted, $this->privkey))
        $data = $decrypted;
    else
        // openssl function fails here, so no plain data is returned
        $data = '';
    return $data;
}
```

I hope you can help what I'm ding wrong here, or might it be a bug in the Cipher class what I'm not expecting :)

EDIT: 
The openssl decryption on the server throws following error message:
`error:0407106B:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:block type is not 02`
The [error](http://hustoknow.blogspot.ca/2013/01/rsa-block-type-is-not-02-error.html) means, that the block type is wrong. Im using the public key in the applet so the block Type should be 02 but it isnt...

EDIT:

**The problem is solved now**. It was a programming error of my own. The modulus was not set correctly (the last byte was always set to zero) so the decryption doesn't work afterwards.

Comment: First, how is the data sent from app to server? If you just put it in an HTTP body it might get treated as chars (not binary) and editted or normalized, which for crypto data is catatrophic; you may need to encode it in base64 or hex (and then decode). Second, I would try writing the encrypted value to a file (which should be exactly 256 octets) and use commandline `openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey pemfile <file1 >file2` and if it complains about padding add `-raw`. This should give a better error instead of just returning nothing, and *if* padding is bad you can see exactly how.

Comment: The data is send over an Android proxy app to the server, but the app only forwards the data (incoming as byte array). For sending the cipher to the server the app uses a http POST Request (sended data and received data in the pho script are the same). The strange thing is, I wrote a normal java application which also encrypts the data with the same public key and the server successfully decrypts it. So I think the problem is due to anything in the applet (JavaCard). 
Thanks, I will try your suggestion with the commandline.

Comment: I don't see you setting the modulus or public exponent anywhere. Did you move out that code or are you just returning zero's or whatever is in the APDU buffer?

Comment: (For edit 9/27) "block type not 02" means *either* (1) the encryption padding was not done correctly, which is unlikely but `rsautl -decrypt -raw` will check for sure, OR (2) the data was corrupted in transit (which you say you've ruled out), OR (3) the decrypting private key does not match the encrypting public key; since you've checked the decrypt side against another (good) source this points suspicion toward the javacard encrypt side. Either (2) or (3) produces total garbage, but block type is the first thing **checked** in that garbage and thus reported as the error.

Comment: I think you need to provide either the complete code and/or APDU Trace Log to make sure the applet is working correctly.

Comment: The problem is solved now! Thanks for your support guys. Especially the comment of dave_thompson which made me look at the modulus setting more in detail. One byte of the modulus was not set correctly caused by a missing counter variable for the modulus array.
So it was my fault that the encryption doesn't work correctly.